# Can someone help me to prove this theorem from Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right*?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, factoring

If $p\in P(\Bbb{R})$ is a nonconstant polynomial, then $p$ has a unique factorization (except for the order of the factors) of the form

> $$p(x)=c(x-\lambda_1)...(x-\lambda_m)(x^2+\alpha_1+\beta_1)...(x^2+\alpha_Mx+\beta_M),$$

where $c,\lambda_1,...\lambda_m \in \Bbb{R}$ and $(\alpha_1,\beta_1),...(\alpha_M,\beta_M)\in\Bbb{R^2}$ with $\alpha_j^2<4\beta_j$ for each $j$

=============================

Comment: Do you mean Axler, as in *Linear Algebra Done Right*? I assume so, since the wording is identical. The proof is in the book: Theorem 4.14.

Comment: This is a version of the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Comment: @bungo I don't have the book, my lecture notes just tell me, the factorization has the form of $(x-\lambda)$, and also $(x-\bar{\lambda})$ is also in the form. combining these two terms to get quadratic term of the required form. What does it mean by combining two terms?

Comment: @Hobbit6094: Well, as Rene said, it's basically the fundamental theorem of algebra. I have Axler's book in front of me; for this theorem, he appeals to the fundamental theorem of algebra, which he states as theorem 4.7. His proof of 4.7 uses but does not prove Liouville's theorem. You can find some proofs here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra

Comment: +1, because anyone who goes by the name "Hobbit" deserves our support!  Good question to boot!  And ***The road goes ever on and on . . .***

Comment: @Bungo here is my confusion: thinking $p$ as $P(\Bbb{C})$, then factor it into $p(z)=c(z-\lambda_1)....(z-\lambda_m)$. then they have nonreal complex. By taking the complex conjugate, $\bar{\lambda}$ is also root.  But how is those get me to the desired from mentioned in the question?

Answer (score 1):

This statement is alluding to the fact that every odd degree polynomial has a real root in $\mathbb{R}$ by intermediate value theorem, and every complex root appeared twice (with its conjugate) in the solution set.

So by fundamental theorem of algebra (which you should check) the polynomial must have at least one root in $\mathbb{C}$. If it is odd degree polynomial, then including the conjugate of that root you can get another odd degree less two polynomial. And in the end you must get at least one real root. For each degree polynomial it is similar, though all roots may be complex in this case. Since we know $(x-\alpha)(x-\overline{\alpha})$ is an irreducible quadratic over $\mathbb{R}$, you get the factorization theorem you needed. You can prove the statement without this little fact, but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental theorem of algebra:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra

is a rather profound theorem which states that if $p$ is an $n$th degree polynomial with complex coefficients, then it can be factored into $n$ linear factors:

$p(x) = c(x-x_1)(x-x_2)\cdots(x-x_n)$

Note that this factorization is unique. To see this, suppose we have two different factorizations

$p(x) = c(x-x_1)(x-x_2)\cdots(x-x_n) = d(x - y_1)(x-y_2)\cdots(x-y_m)$

If any of the $x_i$'s are the same as any of the $y_j$'s, then cancel them from both sides. After doing this, we have two factorizations of the above form where none of the $x_i$'s is the same as a $y_j$, or vice versa.

Now consider $p(x_1)$. Since $x-x_1$ is a factor on the left hand side, we must have $p(x_1) = 0$. But $x - x_1$ is *not* a factor on the right hand side, so if we plug in $x = x_1$ on the right hand side, we get $d(x_1 - y_1)(x_1 - y_2)\cdots(x_1 - y_m)$, where all the factors are nonzero. But this is a contradiction since $p(x_1) = 0$. Thus the assumption that there could be two different factorizations was false.

Let's take the fundamental algebra as given. There are many ways to prove it, but they all require some sophisticated machinery (complex analysis, topology, etc). Axler essentially states but does not prove the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Now let's consider the special case where the coefficients are real-valued. The goal is to factorize $p(x)$ into factors that contain only real coefficients. Certainly if we start with the (possibly complex) factorization

$p(x) = c(x-x_1)(x-x_2)\cdots(x-x_n)$

then some of the $x_j$'s may be real. If so, let's separate these out and rename them as $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots, \lambda_m$. These are the first $m$ factors in Axler's factorization in the problem statement.

So now we just have to deal with the non-real $x_j$'s.

It's not too hard to show by induction that any non-real roots $x_j$ must occur as complex conjugate pairs. That is, if $p(x)$ has real coefficients and $x_j$ is a non-real root, then so is $\overline{x_j}$. Therefore two of the factors are $(x-x_j)(x-\overline{x_j})$. Carrying out the multiplication, we get
$$(x-x_j)(x-\overline{x_j}) = x^2 - (x_j + \overline{x_j}) x + x_j \overline{x_j}$$
Now note that if $z$ is any complex number, $z + \overline{z}$ is real: if we write $z = a + ib$, then $\overline{z} = a - ib$, so $z + \overline{z} = a + ib + a - ib = 2a$.
Another way to express this is $z + \overline{z} = 2\text{Re}(z)$.

Note also that if $z$ is any complex number, $z\overline{z}$ is simply $|z|^2$. To see this, write $z = a+ib$ and $\overline{z} = a-ib$. Then $z\overline{z} = (a + ib)(a - ib) = a^2 + b^2 + aib - aib = a^2 + b^2 = (\sqrt{a^2 + b^2})^2 = |z|^2$.

Applying these facts to the equation above, we get
$$(x-x_j)(x-\overline{x_j}) = x^2 - (x_j + \overline{x_j}) x + x_j \overline{x_j} = x^2 - 2\text{Re}(x_j) x + |x_j|^2$$
which is one of the $(x^2 + \alpha x + \beta)$ in Axler's theorem statement: $\alpha = -2\text{Re}(x_j)$ and $\beta = |x_j|^2$.

Comment: Sorry for all the typos :-( Should be OK now.

Comment: can you also do the proof of uniqueness part? thx

Comment: @Hobbit6094: Uniqueness follows because the factorization given by the fundamental theorem of algebra is unique. The basic idea is as follows: if we have two factorizations $(x-a_1)(x-a_2)\cdots(x-a_n) = (x-b_1)(x-b_2)\cdots(x-b_m)$, then first, cancel any common factors. So none of the $a_i$'s are the same as any of the $b_j$'s. Now simply evaluate the left and right hand sides at, say, $x=a_1$. The left hand side is zero since $(x-a_1)$ is a factor. But the right hand side is nonzero. Therefore the two sides cannot be the same polynomial.

Comment: it seems that your proof has something missing. you prove that unreal root factor could be written into $(x^2+αx+β)$ form. But you missed for those factors with real roots. How do we know that if those factor has real coefficient?

Comment: No, any nonreal root along with its conjugate pair can be combined into the form $(x^2 + \alpha x + \beta)$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are real. I proved this part in my answer. The real roots are the $\lambda_j$'s given in Axler's factorization. We can write them as $(x-\lambda_j)$ as is, because they are already real. We don't need to combine them with any other factors to get real coefficients like we do with the nonreal roots.

Comment: @Hobbit6094: I updated my answer to provide the details of uniqueness and of what happens with the real roots.

Comment: I've just find a pdf of Alexer's book, I find in his proof, there is one part. he factors $p(x)=(x-\lambda)(x-\bar{\lambda})q(x)$, then prove $q$ has only real coeffients. why is this part important?

Comment: my thought is that, if $q$ has only real coeffients, then each nonreal root after factorization, must occur as complex conjugate pairs ? Therefore, the all polynomial $P$ has only real coefficient?

Comment: He needs to show that $q$ has only real coefficients in order to obtain a proof by induction. To do this, he needs to establish that $q$ is a real polynomial with smaller degree than $p$.